# Why can't I use openssl_encrypt?

Tags: php, openssl

I'm trying to implement a call to [openssl_encrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) on my client's web server and I am getting a fatal error `Unknown function: openssl_encrypt()`. I thought requirement was PHP 5.3.0 and above? By the look of the [phpinfo() dump](http://bwagnerdev.com/serverinfo.html) the server is running 5.3.3.

What gives?

Comment: looking at the `phpinfo()` you can check the Configuration Command part, you'll see that you don't have `--with-openssl`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the `openssl_` functions, you have to **a)** have [OpenSSL installed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.requirements.php), and **b)** build PHP with OpenSSL support.  See the [PHP OpenSSL docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php).

> To use PHP's OpenSSL support you must also compile PHP `--with-openssl[=DIR]`

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.requirements.php

> In order to use the OpenSSL functions you need to install the » OpenSSL package. PHP between versions 4.0.5 and 4.3.1 will work with OpenSSL >= 0.9.5. Other versions (PHP <=4.0.4 and >= 4.3.2) require OpenSSL >= 0.9.6.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php

> To use PHP's OpenSSL support you must also compile PHP --with-openssl[=DIR] .