# Call to undefined function openssl_public_encrypt() in PHP

Tags: php, wamp, php-openssl

I am using WAMP 2.4.4. To encrypt a String I used the "**MyEncryption**" class, but the error is:

> Call to undefined function openssl_public_encrypt()

Is there any special library that i must add before using `openssl_public_encrypt()`

```
class MyEncryption
{

    public $pubkey = '...public key here...';
    public $privkey = '...private key here...';

    function encrypt($data)
    {
        if (openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encrypted, $this->pubkey))
            $data = base64_encode($encrypted);
        else
            throw new Exception('Unable to encrypt data. Perhaps it is bigger than the key size?');

        return $data;
    }

}

$url = new MyEncryption();
$d   = "Hello World";   
$enc = $url->encrypt($d);

echo "Encryption is: ", $enc;
```

Comment: You get the error for a webapp or for the command-line? (Related & why I ask: [Composer Warning: openssl extension is missing. How to enable in WAMP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14062055/367456))

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any special library that i must add before using `openssl_public_encrypt()`?

Yes there is, it is called [*OpenSSL*](http://php.net/book.openssl) and you find it documented in the PHP manual here:

- http://php.net/book.openssl

Depending on your operating system flavor the package is called `php-openssl` and all you need to do is to install it. Then it should be automatically available in PHP.

This is similar in the WAMP UI, which you can use to enable php_openssl as well. Only in case you're concerned for the commandline you need to do more work, see the related question:

- [Composer Warning: openssl extension is missing. How to enable in WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14062055/367456)

Comment: You'll never guess what the extension is called. edit: Aww, I liked it better before the edit.

Comment: @Sammitch: Well yeah :D

Answer (score 1):

Please enable the php_openssl extension in the WAMP -> PHP -> PHP Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [phpseclib, a pure PHP RSA implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/intro.html), instead of openssl_public_encrypt. eg.

```
<?php
include_once('Crypt/RSA.php'); 

$pubkey = file_get_contents('/path/to/public.key');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA(); 
$rsa->loadKey($pubkey); 
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1); 
$ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt('ddd');
```

Answer (score -1):

To use the openssl_ functions, you have to

> a) have OpenSSL installed, and
>   b) build PHP with OpenSSL support.

See the PHP OpenSSL docs.

answer taken from [Why can't I use openssl_encrypt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525524/why-cant-i-use-openssl-encrypt)