# PHP OpenSSL Encrypt Issue

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

So I'm trying to encrypt and echo a file with openssl. Getting my file contents works, but after I call the function to encrypt, it doesn't echo anything, as if it were a syntax error.

```
$file = file_get_contents($filename);
//echo $file; // works
$encfile = openssl_encrypt($file, $encmethod, $enckey, 0, $iv);
echo $encfile;
```

Yes, all my encryption keys and everything are valid. Echoing anything after the encryption doesn't work. If anyone knows what's wrong please let me know.

Comment: Check your error log.

Comment: Tell us, what are the values of `$encmethod`, and `$iv`. Also, what is the **byte length** of `$enckey`? Also as requested, check your error log.

Comment: Do you [even have OpenSSL installed with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525524/why-cant-i-use-openssl-encrypt)?

Comment: @MattClark `$encmethod = "AES-256-CBC";` $iv is 16 bytes $enckey is 32 and theyre based off of time and worked fine with a smaller file previously.

Comment: so, what did the logs reveal after what @zerk asked , *anything?* If you don't have access to logs, then set error reporting to catch and display. What version of PHP also?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 14554477 bytes) in /var/www/html/test.php on line 121: /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php56` So I'm assuming the file size is too large. I guess I will need to allow PHP more memory.

Comment: Probably, or you need to find out if there are too many resources running. That, and try increasing it and the max upload file in the .ini files.

Answer (score 1):

I allowed php more memory with

```
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
```

And now it works like a charm.

Comment: I use `ini_set('memory_limit','3G');` on my server lol, really.  But it was only for one time, Ususall PHP only has `1G` but I had to pull 130million rows out of the DB and move them to MongoDB ... lol

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't add more memory.

I faced a similar issue recently.

How did I fix it, I encrypted chunks of the file at a time a few MB, then I separated the base64 encoded chunks with a `:` which doesn't appear in base64.

Then when you decode it you read it tell you get the the `:` decrypt it and move on to the next chunk.

That way you stay well below the memory limit ... :)

See this answer I posted a few days ago  [KLICK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49567436/php-encrypt-streamed-file-from-javascript/49567765#49567765)

-note- I use PHPSecLib for AES, we were already using it for sFTP, and I had to update from `mycrypt` for our Upcoming move to PHP7.